# Libglib-2.0.0 dll not found on windows every time when I try to run Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have installed all the bundles but while trying to run rails server getting error for libglib-2.0-0.dll not found. I have followed https://www.dll-files.com/download/b5970cca5b1ed27d99bc23796fa35584/libglib-2.0-0.dll.html?c=cXFJRlUrMWZTV0hiNGxjbGcya1FTZz09 but still it doesn't work
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error again. Were you able to figure out?